# How does Spark convert RDD's transformation / action to a Logical Plan ？

Tags: apache-spark, codegen

I'm learning Spark's CodeGen mechanism, but got confused by the way Spark convert RDD's transformation / action to Logical Plan.
The Spark Application as follow:

```
 def sparkTest(): Any = {

    val spark = SparkInit.spark

    import spark.implicits._

    val data = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

    // closure start

    val const = 3

    def mulBy(factor: Double) = (x: Double) => factor * x

    val mulByval = mulBy(const)

    // closure end

    val testRDD = data.toDS()
    val filterRDD = testRDD.filter(i =>
      mulByval(i) <= 7
    )

    filterRDD.collect()

    filterRDD.foreach(i =>
      println(i)
    )


  }
```

I tried to trace the source code, but found when then code goes to Dataset.collect, the queryExecution is already generated.

```
 def collect(): Array[T] = withAction("collect", queryExecution)(collectFromPlan)
```

The queryExecution is as follow

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'TypedFilter <function1>, int, [StructField(value,IntegerType,false)], unresolveddeserializer(upcast(getcolumnbyordinal(0, IntegerType), IntegerType, - root class: "scala.Int"))
+- LocalRelation [value#46]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
value: int
TypedFilter <function1>, int, [StructField(value,IntegerType,false)], cast(value#46 as int)
+- LocalRelation [value#46]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
TypedFilter <function1>, int, [StructField(value,IntegerType,false)], value#46: int
+- LocalRelation [value#46]

== Physical Plan ==
*Filter <function1>.apply$mcZI$sp
+- LocalTableScan [value#46]
```

But I can't find when and where the Logical Plan generate.
Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of a mixup here. The RDD api doesn't actually generate plans. They exist as a primitive or old api that Datasets leverage to do work. In your particular example the query plan begins to be constructed (although it is lazy) when you write this line.

```
val testRDD = data.toDS()
```

After this you no longer have an RDD, you have a DataSet which is encoded from the result of the linage of "data". You can see the plan of any dataset by calling the explain method to get more details.

So to summarize

- Every DataSet has an [queryExecution](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L163) on initialization by design.
- RDDs have no logical Plan (or any codegen)
- RDDS turned into DataSets have a plan whose first step is running through the RDD's dependency tree.

Looking at your code in more detail, there is never actually an RDD in use. You start with a Collection and go directly to a Dataset which creates a LocalTableScan which basically just coverts the values to the InternalRowRepresentation and parallelizes them. See [LocalTableScanExec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/LocalTableScanExec.scala#L48-L56) for details

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have one more question.
That's what I understand now: 
when a Dataset is initialized, it will generate a plan by all this Dataset's transformation and action.
And Spark will generator executable code on the basis of execution plan.
What spark will serialize as a closure and send to its Executors is the generated code by spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage rather than the actual Dataset's transfromation or action.
 I am not sure whether I understand it correctly.

Comment: The logical plan is transformed into a Physical plan. The physical plan is a set of nodes which may or may not contain codegen information. Those nodes which occur in the same stage have their codegen methods fused together into a WholeStageCodgen.

Dataset transformations return a new Dataset with usually one additional logical node (or possibly many). Actions usually add a terminating logical node and then immediately start the execution of the corresponding physical plan.